# How to localize datatype messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to localize datatype messages in MVC4 "The field Date must be a date."

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date be a date." id="Date" name="Date"  value="" >
```

I using:

```
public class LocalizedDataTypeAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<DataTypeAttribute>

        {
            public LocalizedDataTypeAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, DataTypeAttribute attribute) : base(metadata, con

text, attribute)
        {
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization.Global);
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyDataFormat";
        }

    }
```

Also LocalizedDataTypeAttributeAdapter register in Global.asax

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(DataTypeAttribute), typeof(LocalizedDataTypeAttributeAdapter));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider

Take it https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.cs

and change

```
private static string GetUserResourceString(ControllerContext controllerContext, string resourceName)
        {
            string result = null;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ResourceClassKey) && (controllerContext != null) && (controllerContext.HttpContext != null))
            {
                //result = controllerContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(ResourceClassKey, resourceName, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) as string;
                result = GlobalRes.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Then set it as the `DefaultModelBinder` during the `Application_Start` in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{

   var existingProvider = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Single(x => x is ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider);
   ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(existingProvider);
   ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new myClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider()); //!!
   myClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = typeof(GlobalRes).Name;
   DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = typeof(GlobalRes).Name;
}
```

Comment: What is GlobalRes reference? And MvcResources reference? Tell me please. And also you sad "After it write in Global.asax" WHICH METHOD? Very bad suggestion.

Comment: @CanÜrek GlobalRes seems to be the resource class name, identical to the name of the resource file. So in this case the *.resx file would be `GlobalRes.resx`. Replace `GlobalRes` with the name of your resource class.

Comment: But regardless, this is not working in MVC 5, I haven't found a single working solution to get the localization of the validation messages done, at least for the date-error-message. That one seems to be hardcoded. Good job.